# Change navigation header background color

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Struggling to understand how to change the navigation header bar background color.
I'm Using react navigation and Expo to build my app.

`backgroundColor` does not seem to do anything. Any idea how to do this?

My code is below:

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: 'My App',
    headerTintColor: Colors.DarkBlue,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    headerLeft:
      <HeaderBarItem to='InfoScreen' title='App info' />,
    headerRight:
      <HeaderBarItem to='FeedbackScreen' title='Feedback' />
  });
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This should work:

```js
static navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: 'My App',
    headerTintColor: Colors.DarkBlue,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    headerLeft:
      <HeaderBarItem to='InfoScreen' title='App info' />,
    headerRight:
      <HeaderBarItem to='FeedbackScreen' title='Feedback' />
  });
```

Comment: @Aakash where does this  Colors.DarkBlue and <HeaderBarItem come from

Comment: Those are just component and variable from the question @JP

Answer (score 13):

I tried many answers throughout the forums but couldn't find the working solution. Finally below worked for me and will for you if you are using latest RN:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Main}
            options={{ title: 'Welcome', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#e7305b'
           } }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: quite explanatory compared to other solutions

Answer (score 12):

> Paste this in your targeted screen

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   return {
      title: 'Screen Title',
      headerTintColor: 'royalblue',
      headerStyle: {
         backgroundColor: '#fff'
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use inside your view component

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor = '#fff' />
```

This worked for me on android

Don't forget to import **StatusBar from 'react-native'** of course